# When you use findViewById, what is the object that invokes this method?

Tags: java, android

I am programming for android devices on Android Studio.

To my understanding, when I declare and assign a Button like this in my MainActivity.java:

```
mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
```

The compiler automatically substitutes this:

```
mTrueButton = (Button) com.testapp.mytestapp.MainActivity.findViewById(R.id.true_button);
```

But if I actually type in the second statement, I get a warning about non-static methods cannot be referenced from a static context.

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at its signature: **public View findViewById (int id)**

As it's not static, you should call it from an instantiated class and this is the reason of the message you're getting.

To answer your question, the method is part of Activity. In the end, you can call it on an instance of Activity.

In your case you're inside an Activity instance, so you can refer to this instance with the keyword **this**.

Answer (score 0):

I think retrieve it with View.findViewById() or Activity.findViewById(). 
[View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) 
[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity you have not imported R.java file 
SO its taking full reference 
Import R.java(your project's not android.R) of your package will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

The method called is `getWindow().findViewById(id);`. To call this method in an activity, you first have to set it's view with `setContentView(view)`. Or you can inflate a view yourself, and call the method findViewById() on the view you inflated.